# Convert SQL Query to Hibernate CriteriaQuery

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria, criteriaquery

I'd like to convert it to use the javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder, but am unsure what do, any help is much appreciated!

`SELECT * FROM User u INNER JOIN Teacher t ON t.emp_id = u.emp_id WHERE u.college_id=:college_id AND u.Book.sub_code=:sub_code AND t.lang=:lang`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The retrieval of the entity manager depends on your framework and your use case. The solution assumes that you have `collegeId`, `subCode` and `lang` as given values in your method.

You create a query for the `User` which you have in your `SELECT` and create a `Root` for this class.

```java
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<User> cq = cb.createQuery(User.class);
Root<User> root = cq.from(User.class);
```

Then, you join the different classes. As I assume that `Book` is also a needed class, I would join this as well. You do not have to mention on which ID the joins should happen because you already mentioned which value is the ID with the annotation `@Id`.

```java
Join<User, Teacher> teacherJoin = root.join(User_.TEACHER);
Join<User, Book> bookJoin = root.join(User_.BOOK);
```

The different `WHERE` conditions can be added to the criteria query. To link several `WHERE` conditions, I add the conditions to a list (to eventually combine them).

```java
List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
predicates.add(cb.equal(root.get(User_.COLLEGE_ID), collegeId));
predicates.add(cb.equal(bookJoin.get(Book_.SUB_CODE), subCode));
predicates.add(cb.equal(teacherJoin.get(Teacher_.LANG), lang));
```

Eventually, you have to execute the constructed query.

```java
cq
    .select(root)
    .where(cb.and(predicates.toArray()));

return entityManager.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
```

The above answer uses the JPA Metamodel Generator to prevent you from typing your actual reference names as strings. For example, the call `User_.TEACHER` gives you the actual string which refers to the `Teacher` object within `User`.

The following example shows the above code snippets merged together in a function.

```java
public List<User> findAllByCollegeIdAndBookSubCodeAndTeacherLang(
        String collegeId,
        int subCode,
        Lang lang) {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<User> cq = cb.createQuery(User.class);
    Root<User> root = cq.from(User.class);
    Join<User, Teacher> teacherJoin = root.join(User_.TEACHER);
    Join<User, Book> bookJoin = root.join(User_.BOOK);
    
    List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
    predicates.add(cb.equal(root.get(User_.COLLEGE_ID), collegeId));
    predicates.add(cb.equal(bookJoin.get(Book_.SUB_CODE), subCode));
    predicates.add(cb.equal(teacherJoin.get(Teacher_.LANG), lang));
    
    cq
        .select(root)
        .where(cb.and(predicates.toArray()));

    return entityManager.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
}
```